# How I add same value in 2 rows using primary key in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

I have database table like this:

```
[Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SecondId] INT NOT NULL,
```

I want to add same value in `[SecondId]` of second row using `[Id]` along first row when I create new rows like

```
1 1 (first raw)
2 1 (second raw) [id is different, but secondId is same]
3 3 (first raw)
4 3 (second raw) [id is different, but secondId is same]
```

I hope this action be caused when I add new rows using HttpPost

Would you help me please??

In summary:

1. I want to create 2 rows when I use HttpPost
2. second row's `[secondId]` has same value with first row's `[id]`

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Have you tried anything yet? What are your efforts?

Comment: This question is too broad and suffers from various problems.  It feels like you want someone to write you an entire application.  Show effort and come back with specific issues.

Comment: @DavidG I haven't tried yet beacuse have no idea... and I want to create 1-1 chatroom database having each rows for 2 users and secondid is roomId

Comment: Either that or rephrase it more precisely. The logic involved probably doesn't depend on a database or httpPost. You have a list of objects with two int properties, and you want to...

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Yes, I know I'm rudeness... But really have no idea;; sorry

Comment: @JaeWangLee - Start by looking at existing code.  Codeproject and github both have tons of code you can use for reference.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that may help you out with the logic part of your question. It takes a list of items that have a `PrimaryId` and a `SecondaryId` and will return to you the *next* item that should be added to that list.

First, here's the `Item` class we're using:

```
public class Item
{
    public int PrimaryId { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryId { get; set; }
}
```

The method figures out what to assign to the `PrimaryId` and `SecondaryId` of the *next* item by looking at the *last* item in the list (`lastItem`). It then creates a new item with a `PrimaryId` that is `lastItem.PrimaryId + 1`, and it assigns a `SecondaryId` based on whether or not `lastItem.PrimaryId` is odd or even.

Notice that if the previous item's `PrimaryId` is even, then the next item's `SecondaryId` is equal to the previous item's `PrimaryId + 1`. Otherwise it's equal to the previous item's `PrimaryId`.

Here's the method:

```
public static Item GetNextItem(List<Item> items)
{
    // If there are no existing items, return the default first item
    if (items == null || items.Count == 0) 
    {
        return new Item {PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryId = 1};
    }

    // Otherwise, grab the last item in the list
    var lastItem = items[items.Count - 1];

    // And use it's PrimaryId to determine the values for the next item's properties
    return new Item
    {
        PrimaryId = lastItem.PrimaryId + 1,
        SecondaryId = lastItem.PrimaryId % 2 == 0
            ? lastItem.PrimaryId + 1
            : lastItem.PrimaryId
    };
}
```

And here it is in use:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var items = new List<Item>();

    // Populate the list of items using our method to continually get the next item
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        items.Add(GetNextItem(items));
    }

    // Now output the items to the Console window
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.PrimaryId} {item.SecondaryId}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]